# RxJava sequence filtering

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Suppose I have two observables: A and B which emit items: 
A: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
B: 2, 4, 6

Is there a way to filter first sequence by removing items which are also in second sequence?

[edit]
required data flow: Load all items from observable B (bList), then load items from A, filtering them based on the criteria: !bList.contains(item)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RxJava offers a number of [filtering operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables).

Specifically, you want `distinct()`. You can pass a function that checks for item equality if you want to define your own equality check for your objects.

Note that internally, `distinct()` tracks objects using a `HashSet`, so if your objects do not hash correctly (e.g. two "equal" objects do not have the same hash code), then you will want to use that optional parameter to define your own check for distinctiveness.

If you aren't combining the streams, then you just want to use `filter()`, and in your filtering function check if the your Obeservable has already emitted that item. In this scenario one of your Observables *must* complete before the second can be filtered, because RxJava cannot predict the future of what items will be emitted.

For example:

```
Observable a = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4);
Observable b = Observable.just(3, 4, 5, 6);

// If you simply want a list of distinct items:
Observable uniqueItems = a.merge(b).distinct()

// If you just want to filter "a" so it contains none of the items in "b"
Observable filteredA = b.toList().flatMap(itemsInB -> {
    a.filter(item -> !itemsInB.contains(item));
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have paraphrased the last paragraph. I'm looking for a clean solution to do exactly that.

Comment: I've added an example demonstrating how you might use `filter()` to achieve what you want.